# Reduce objects from array if object's property contains any of substrings

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to reduce all objects inside arrays that their property "Title" contains any substring included in separate JSON file. I been trying to filter the arrays by objects property but it doesnt work actually and reduce() method would be better to achieve it.

The goal is to do some math for objects that are not excluded, for example:
If any object has property Title different than included (qa, quality assurance, software tester) then we should remove it and dont take this under calculation

I was trying with noobie way to achieve it but can't get this working and I think what is better is to transform the positionsArray by reducing the objects that shouldnt be taken under calculation and then do the math.

My function

```
calculateSoftwareExperience: async function () {
      fileToCurate.forEach(candidate => {
        const positionsArray = candidate.softwareIndustryPositions;
        console.log(positionsArray)
        //const reducedArray = positionsArray.reduce(x => x.title)
        
        //console.log(positionsArray)
        if (Array.isArray(positionsArray) && positionsArray.length) {
          // array exists and is not empty
          positionsArray.forEach(position => {
            let title = position.title;
            
            if (titlesIncluded.some(x => title.includes(x))) {
              console.log(title)
              const firstFrom = positionsArray[positionsArray.length - 1].from;
              const lastTo = positionsArray[0].to;
              let diff = lastTo - firstFrom;
              let days = (diff * 1000) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000) / 1000;
              let months = Math.floor(days / 31);
              //console.log(firstFrom, "to", lastTo, "diff = ", months);
              candidate.softwareIndustryExp = months;
              //console.log(months)
            }
          });
        } else {
          candidate.softwareIndustryExp = 0;
        }
      });
    },
```

positionsArray output

```
[
  {
    flagged: false,
    from: 2019-10-31T23:00:00.000Z,
    to: 2020-01-31T23:00:00.000Z,
    title: 'junior manual tester'
  },
  {
    flagged: false,
    from: 2018-05-31T22:00:00.000Z,
    to: 2019-09-30T22:00:00.000Z,
    title: 'junior administrator'
  },
  {
    flagged: false,
    from: 2016-03-31T22:00:00.000Z,
    to: 2016-03-31T22:00:00.000Z,
    title: 'praktykant'
  }
]
```

input with substrings

```
    "titlesIncluded": [
        "qa",
        "quality engineer",
        "qa automation",
        "software tester",
        "qa engineer"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it with reduce() method but I have done it my noobie way. What I am doing is basically creating new object and filter by property title, then pushing every object inside array and doing proper math. Here is the code:

```
    calculateSoftwareExperience: async function () {
      fileToCurate.forEach(candidate => {
        const positionsArray = candidate.softwareIndustryPositions;

        if (Array.isArray(positionsArray) && positionsArray.length) {
          let roletypeArray = [];
          positionsArray.forEach(position => {
            let title = position.title;
            if (titlesIncluded.some(x => title.includes(x))) {
              let pos = {};
              pos.title = title;
              pos.from = position.from;
              pos.to = position.to;
              roletypeArray.push(position);
            }
          });

          if (Array.isArray(roletypeArray) && roletypeArray.length) {
            const firstFrom = roletypeArray[roletypeArray.length - 1].from;
            const lastTo = roletypeArray[0].to;
            let diff = lastTo - firstFrom;
            let days = (diff * 1000) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000) / 1000;
            let months = Math.floor(days / 31);
            candidate.softwareIndustryExp = months;
          } else {
            candidate.softwareIndustryExp = 0;
          }
        } else {
          candidate.softwareIndustryExp = 0;
        }
      });
    },
```